# Accessing nested JSON value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access a nested JSON variable (water discharge value, here: https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&sites=01610400&parameterCd=00060&siteStatus=all) using JavaScript.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.value.timeSeries.values.value.value;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&sites=01610400&parameterCd=00060&siteStatus=all", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I can access the top level variables (e.g., myObj.name returns "ns1:timeSeriesResponseType"). However, trying to access the discharge value at value.timeSeries.values.value.value returns nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Look at the FasterXML/Jackson library in JS and look for the JsonNode object

Comment: `values` is an array. You need to select a specific index

Comment: It looks like there are a few arrays in there. this will get a value `myObj.value.timeSeries[0].values[0].value[0].value` but you need to take into consideration that some of it is in the form of an array and not an object.

Comment: @NilsKähler - that was it. Thanks, I was overloooking the array.